# Как удалить документ из firebase по его id динамически

Tags: javascript, firebase

У меня есть коллекция в firebase 'posts'. Я добавляю новые элементы динамически, но проблема в том что у меня не получается удалять элементы из firebase.

```
db.collection('posts').doc(что мне передать сюда?).delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильный код:

```
db.collection('posts').get()
    .then(post => {
        post.forEach(doc => {
            doc.ref.delete()
        })
})
```